# How do I set SBS 2008 as DHCP-server? I had the router as DHCP-server before

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, dhcp-server

Until yesterday, we had no server at our network, so we used our router, D-Link DFL 200 as DHCP server. The router has IP: `192.168.1.1` and all clients has IP in the range: `192.168.1.10 - 192.168.1.20`.

Yesterday I installed a Windows SBS 2008, and I was recommended to use that one as DHCP-server instead and heard that it was pre-configured as DHCP-server. This server has IP: `192.168.1.2`.

Now I would like to turn off the DHCP-server in the router and use the SBS 2008 as DHCP-server. In the router I has changed from **Use built-in DHCP Server** to **Relay DHCP request to other DHCP server:** `192.168.1.2`.

Then I tried from a Windows XP client to renew the IP-address but that failed. The DHCP service on SBS 2008 was stopped, but I started it again, and now is it "Started", but I can still not renew the IP-address from the Windows XP client.

**How do I set the Windows SBS 2008 as DHCP-server?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to relay DHCP. You want to completely disable DHCP on the router. Once that's done, see if it works. If it doesn't, re-run the "connect to the internet" wizard is SBS.

Answer (score 1):

First, disable DHCP Server on D-Link. You do not need the DHCP relay.

[Manual](http://sbs.seandaniel.com/2008/10/do-i-absolutely-have-to-run-dhcp-on-sbs.html) how run DHCP on SBS 2008.

For debug problem, install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to Windows XP.